# SVD of Cholesky Factor

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, numerical-linear-algebra, proof-explanation, svd

I am working through the book Fundamentals of Matrix Computations by David Watkins, and I ran into this one and it's stumping me.  In my head, I understand the basic premise of it. However, I can't put pen to paper as to proving it.  Proofs are not my strong point.

Let $M\in\Bbb{R}$ be positive definite, and let $R$ be the Cholesky factor of $M$, so that $M = R^TR$.

Show that $||M||_2 = ||R||_2^2$ and $\kappa_2(M) = \kappa_2(R)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ R = U \sigma V^t$ be the singular value decomposition of the real matrix $R$ where $U^tU = I$ and $V^tV = $ and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements ordered in the non-increasing order.  The largest singular value $\sigma_1$ is the 2-norm of the matrix $R$. That is, $\|R\|_2 = \sigma_1$.

However, $M = R^tR = V \Sigma U^t U \Sigma V^t = V \Sigma^2 V^t $. The 2-norm of $M$ is then given by the largest eigenvalue of $M$ which is given by $\sigma_1^2$. Thus, $\|M\|_2 = \|R\|_2^2$. I am leaving the final step to you.

Note that in this case, the SVD of $M$ is identical to the symmetric eigenvalue decomposition of $M$.